# Spree Install Error: Could not find gem 'spree_skrill (>= 0) ruby'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am new to ROR, Now i am installing **Spree** , these following step

```
gem install rails -v 3.1.4
rails new mystore
cd mystore
spree install
```

After that here showing this error

```
gemfile  spree
     gemfile  spree_usa_epay
     gemfile  spree_skrill
         run  bundle install from "."
Could not find gem 'spree_skrill (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
precompiling  assets
Could not find gem 'spree_skrill (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Comment: What happens when you do `./mystore/bundle install` and then `spree install`?

Comment: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    spree_usa_epay (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (<= 3.1.3, >= 3.1.1) ruby

    rails (3.2.2)

Comment: Interesting... for some reason spree_usa_epay allows a range of Rails (which yours is not fitting in to) or rails 3.2.2. SO... you can do `gem update rails`, let it go to 3.2.2 and see where that takes you.

Comment: Now i just update the rails using this command `gem update rails` After that its showing this error `Updating installed gems`
`Nothing to update`

Comment: What happens if you try `gem install rails -version "3.1.3"`?

Comment: Still showing same error `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    spree_usa_epay (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (<= 3.1.3, >= 3.1.1) ruby

    rails (3.2.2)
`

Comment: Hey, Here i am using RVM, now i check my rails version showing Rails 3.2.2, please hep me...

Comment: Can you please show us your Gemfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gem install spree_skrill
```

And if, after that, you are getting "Could not find gem 'spree_usa_epay (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine."

```
gem install spree_usa_epay
```

after that, I tried running >> spree install again and it worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error **can't find gem spree (>= 0.a) with executable spree (Gem::GemNotFoundException)**

Then I run this command:

```
gem install spree -v '>= 0.a'
```

It worked...